# Using RemoveWords in tm_map in R on words loaded from a file

Tags: r, tm

I have seen several questions about using the `removewords` function in the `tm_map` package of R in order to remove either `stopwords()` or hard coded words from a corpus. However, I am trying to remove words stored in a file (currently csv, but I don't care which type). Using the code below, I don't get any errors, but my words are still there. Could someone please explain what is wrong?

```
#install.packages('tm')
library(tm)

setwd("c://Users//towens101317//Desktop")

problem_statements <- read.csv("query_export_results_100.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
problem_statements_text <- paste(problem_statements, collapse=" ")
problem_statements_source <- VectorSource(problem_statements_text)

my_stop_words <- read.csv("mystopwords.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE)
my_stop_words_text <- paste(my_stop_words, collapse=" ")

corpus <- Corpus(problem_statements_source)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, my_stop_words_text)

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm2 <- as.matrix(dtm)

frequency <- colSums(dtm2)
frequency <- sort(frequency, decreasing=TRUE)

head(frequency)
```

Comment: Could you add to your question a call of inspect(corpus) before the tm_map line so we can see what your corpus looks like?

Comment: Shouldn't the last argument in  `corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, my_stop_words_text)` be a function rather than a list of characters? If I recall correctly, the usual syntax is `corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords())` where `stopwords()` is a function defined in the `tm` package that returns a list of words. Maybe you can try to define such a function with your stopwords and see if that works.

Comment: The problem was that read.csv() created a table but I needed a vector. The ReadLines() function does this. I changed my read statement like this and it  worked.:     my_stop_words <- readLines("mystopwords.csv")       Thanks for the help.